# Odoo: How to place debug lines in server code for viewing in /var/log/odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, logging, odoo

I did the following:

1. Placed some print debug lines in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py`
2. Restart the Odoo server via `sudo service odoo restart`
3. Login to the Odoo server and perform the actions that will trigger the debug line in step 1.

But my print debug lines aren't appearing in `/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log`

Am I missing any steps above? How to debug Python code in Odoo in general? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1-** In your python file you can define a `_logger`

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyClass(models.Model):

    # [...]

    _logger.debug("Debug message")
```

Modify this attribute in your configuration file

```
log_level = debug
```

Restart the service, and the message will be printed in your log file:

```
2015-08-23 17:32:05,401 2249 DEBUG ? openerp.service.server: Debug message
```

**2 -** You can use `pudb` to set a breakpoint like following:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):

    # [...]

    import pudb;pu.db # This will create a breakpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the following, but haven't tried it yet. Will report my findings and confirm once I have.

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-debug-python-code-in-open-erp-28046

Comment: Apparently, `_logger` was already being employed profusely throughout the Python file I was editing. And so I just followed suit. Keeping the above references for posterity.